# Ubuntu server 16.04 - standard system utilities

Tags: server, apt, 16.04

During the installation of Ubuntu server 16.04 I opted out from installing "standard system utilities" by mistake. Is there any way to install them with apt-get install command easily ?

Comment: See [Ubuntu Server Initial Packages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/820023/ubuntu-server-initial-packages)

Comment: @steeldriver Running sudo tasksel opens up a window which has only one option that I can choose from "Manual package selection". Unfortunately selecting it and pressing <OK> returns error "Can't exect "/usr/lib/tasksel/packages/manual": No such file or directory at /usr/bin/tasksel"

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-standard
```

See http://packages.ubuntu.com/ for package names and info