# Ubuntu Server Initial Packages?

Tags: server, apt, 16.04, system-installation, package-management

You know when you get to the "Select and Install Software" part of Ubuntu Server installation and you pick the options you want (Lets say LAMP) but actually pick the wrong ones (I needed Virtual Machine Host) and it's too late to go back to that screen and you're too lazy to reinstall? Well what are the metapackages (Hoping that they're used for those installs) for each of the options, and will a simple

> sudo apt install (Package)

or

> sudo apt remove (Package) / sudo apt purge (Package)

Do the trick?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No need to search for package names or even reinstalling - you can easily re-launch that graphical package-selection dialog as follows:

```
sudo tasksel
```

And end up with something similar to this

[image]

Enjoy ;)

Comment: Yes I just realized "Tasksel" but I want to use a similar interface that ONLY includes Server Packages from the Ubuntu Server "Select and Install Software" and specific Package Names would be helpful. @dufte